# What's wrong with my Spring Batch context?

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd, spring-batch

Here is the context for Spring Batch:

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd">
  <b:job id="bar" job-repository="my-job-repository">
    <b:step id="foo">
      <b:tasklet transaction-manager="my-transaction-manager">
        <b:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter"/>
      <b:tasklet>
    </b:step>
  </b:job>
</beans:beans>
```

This is what Spring Batch says:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found
starting with element 'b:tasklet'. One of
'{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch":transaction-attributes,
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch":no-rollback-exception-classes,
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch":listeners,
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean,
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref}' is expected.
```

What's wrong with my XML?

ps. I'm using `org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:2.1.7.RELEASE`

Comment: Maybe you should read the error message... It pretty much explains your error. (Missing a required tag)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot to close the `tasklet` tag. probably copied from [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#configuringAStep) and replicated the mistake

Comment: Slashies. Slashies. Slashies.